# Google Map script with local json file data not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get some json markers to display on my map.

The map is actually appearing but no pointers are being displayed and the position of the map is way off.

Here is the js code:

```
<script>

    $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function() { 
    // This URL won't work on your localhost, so you need to change it
    // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
    $.getJSON( 'locations.json', function(data) { 
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 
                'bounds': true 
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': marker.content }, this);
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is the contents of the json file:

```
{"locations":[{"id":"14","location":"(50.8765125,
 -1.1504182944499557)"}]}
```

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the structure of your `json` file I'd say your're trying to access undefined properties of each item in `data.markers`. `locations` is an array of objects with two properties: `id` is a `String` and `locations` is an `array` of length 2. So why this code?

```
marker.latitude
marker.longitude
marker.content
```

Maybe you should try

```
marker.location[0]
marker.location[1]
```

First you should confirm your json output:

```
$.getJSON( 'locations.json', function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
}
```

And post it in your question...

If it's ok try like this:

```
$.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
            'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.location[0], marker.location[1]), 
            'bounds': true 
        }).click(function() {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': marker.id }, this);
        });
    });
```

... Actually I'm not sure why you use `data.marker` also and not `data.locations`

Comment: Can you confirm the content of the 'data' variable in your console and post it plz?

Comment: Strange: Tried this: $.getJSON('locations.json', function(data) { 
 alert(data);
});  ...and I go no alert at all :o/  I know the file is there at the same level as the index.html

Comment: So you've got no callback... try /locations.json as url... And try to log network transactions with firebug or chrome console to check the file path and response headers.

Comment: Can't find the error :o/ The location of he json file is correct ... so I don't know what else to do

Comment: in Google chrome's console, go to the Network tab and at the bottom click the 'xhr' button to monitor ajax requests. Then you can see whether the json file loads correctly. and what it looks like.

Comment: You found your way around this?